Neighborhood around a punctured curve and hyperbolic metric
This question is related to this the neighboorhood of a node of an abelian form(Plumbing a cylinder )
I found this argument on the book "Geometry and Topology of Manifolds. 10th China-Japan Conference 2014", page 47. I will transcribe and write my doubts in bold.

Let $(C, \{p_1, \dots, p_n\})$ be a Riemann surface of genus $g$ and
$n$-marked points. Equivalently, we may consider the punctured surface
of $C$ with marked points removed: $$ C^* = C \setminus \{p_1, \dots, p_n\}. $$ When $C^*$ is of negative Euler characteristic, $C^*$ has a
complete hyperbolic metric $\rho$ (a complete metric of constant
curvature $-1$) under which its punctures become cusps of the
hyperbolic metric. Locally, the geometry of these cusps can be
described by applying the uniformization theorem to $C$ at a puncture
$p$ as follows.
Let $\mathbb{H} = \{\zeta = x + iy \mid y > 0\}$ be the upper
half-plane with the Poincaré metric: $$ \rho_0(\zeta) = \frac{1}{(\mathrm{Im}(\zeta))^2} d\zeta d\bar{\zeta}. $$ Let $$
 \mathfrak{D} =\dfrac{ \{\zeta \in \mathbb{H} \mid \mathrm{Im}(\zeta) \geq 1\}}{ \zeta \sim \zeta + 1} $$ be a cylinder, and $\rho_0$
induces a metric on $\mathfrak{D}$, which is still denoted by
$\rho_0$. At any punctured point $p \in \{p_1, \dots, p_n\}$ there
exists a neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ in $C$ such that $$ (U_p, \rho) \cong (D, \rho_0). $$

1. I do not understand what the isomorphism is.
I think that taking a chart $\varphi_p:\overline{U_p}\to\mathbb C$, such that $\varphi(U_p)=\{z\in\mathbb C.|z|\leq1\}$, $\varphi(\partial U_p)=\{|z|=1\}$ and $\varphi(p)=0$. For $0<\varepsilon<1$, the set $\{x\in U_p, \varepsilon<|\varphi(x)|\leq 1\}$ is isomorphic to the annulus
$$\{z\in\mathbb{C},\varepsilon<|z|\leq 1\},$$ and this latter is isomorphic to a cylinder
$$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3,x^2+y^2=1,1\leq z<1+\varepsilon\}$$
Taking $\varepsilon\to 0$ we have that $U_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{D}$.

Moreover, we require that all $U_{p_i}$'s are disjoint from each
other. Hence, we fix an identification: $$ \zeta_p : U_p \to D. $$ Let
$z_p = e^{2\pi i \zeta_p}$. Then $z_p$ is a local complex coordinate
on $U_p$ with $z_p(p) = 0$...

2. Why is $z_p(p)=0$?

... and $U_p = \{z_p \mid \ln |z_p| < -2\pi\}$. For any $c \in (0, e^{-2\pi})$, the circle $|z_p| = c$ is called a closed horocycle at
$p$ of the hyperbolic length $$ \ell(c) = -\frac{2\pi}{\log c}. $$ We
call $(U_p, z_p)$ a horodisc of $p$.

Any hint will be appreciated.

It is a badly written paper. By an isomorphism they mean an isometry. You will be better off reading something better written.

Thank you for your response. I have searched in several places but haven't found anything. If you know of something, I would appreciate it if you could share it.

Yes, later, when I have a bit more time.

Thank you very much!

Hi @MoisheKohan, were you able to find references about the result? Thank you!

Ok, here is what this article is saying.

First of all, every Riemann surface $S$ of hyperbolic type (in your case, this means that $g=0$ and $n\ge 3$, or $g=1$ and $n\ge 1$, or $g\ge 2$) is biholomorphic to the quotient of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H$ by a discrete torision-free group of hyperbolic isometries, $\Gamma$. Additionally, you know that $S$ has a compactification as a Riemann surface $C$, so that $S$ is biholomorphic to $C\setminus \{p_1,...,p_n\}$. Then there are $n$ pairwise disjoint closed disks $D_i,i=1,...,n$ in $C$, which are neighborhoods of the points $p_i$. Set $D_i^*:= D_i-\{p_i\}$.
The paper uses the notation $U_{p_i}$ for these disks, which I prefer to avoid.

Now, it is a fact of the theory of Riemann surfaces that one can choose the disks $D_i$ so that the preimage of each $D^*_i$ in $\mathbb H$ is the $\Gamma$-orbit of a horodisk $B_i\subset \mathbb H$. The latter means that it is either a Euclidean closed disk tangent to the real line $\mathbb R=\partial \mathbb H$ (with the tangency point removed), or it is a half-plane of the form
$$
\{z: Im(z)\ge t\}
$$
for some $t>0$. Let $\Gamma_i< \Gamma$ denote the stabilizer of $B_i$ in $\Gamma$. Now, applying a (hyperbolic) isometry $\alpha_i$ of $\mathbb H$, we can send each of these horodisks $B_i$ to the "standard" horodisk
$$
B=\{z: Im(z)\ge 1\}
$$
and $\alpha_i\Gamma_i\alpha_i^{-1}$ is a cyclic group of isometries
of $\mathbb H$ preserving $B$. Hence, it is an infinite cyclic group generated by a translation $\gamma_i: z\mapsto z+ r_i$, $r_i>0$. One can prove that, indeed, the disjoint disks $D_i$ can be chosen so that $r_i=1$:
$$
\gamma: z\mapsto z+1. 
$$
This is a consequence of the Shimizu's Lemma (and is a nontrivial fact). Given this, I will assume that $r_i=1$. Then the cyclic subgroup generated by  $\gamma$ has fundamental domain in $B$ of the form
$$
F=\{z: 0\le Re(z)\le 1, Im(z)\ge 1\}.
$$
Taking the quotient of $B$ by $\langle \gamma\rangle$ amounts to considering the fundamental domain $F$ with the identification $z\sim z+1$. The hyperbolic metric from $\mathbb H$ projects to a hyperbolic metric on $\mathfrak D= F/\sim$. The quotient $\mathfrak D=B/\langle \gamma\rangle$, in turn, projects diffeomorphically to the surface $\mathbb H/\Gamma$. There is some abuse of notation happening here, the natural projection is from the disk $B_i$ to $B_i/\Gamma_i$ and from there to $\mathbb H/\Gamma$. But our isometry $\alpha_i$ allows us to isometrically identify $B_i$ and $B$, so no harm is done. Recall that we biholomorphically identify $S$ and $\mathbb H/\Gamma$. Since the horodisk $B_i$ was a component of the preimage of $D^*_i$ under the covering map $\mathbb H\to S$, what we got is a biholomorphic isomorphism
$$
\phi_i: \mathfrak D \cong D^*_i. 
$$
This is what the paper is saying. Thus, the only nontrivial ingredient in this entire story is Shimizu's lemma.

The next fact that the article is using is that the quotient $\mathfrak D$ is biholomorphic to the closed unit  disk $D\subset \mathbb C$ (with the origin removed). This biholomorphism is done via the exponential map
$$
f: z\mapsto \exp(2\pi i z)
$$
(the article uses the notation $z_p$ for $f$, which I dislike). Namely, you check that $f\circ \gamma=f$, and for $z, w\in F$, $f(z)=f(w)$ if and only if $z=w$ or $z=w\pm 1$ (in the latter cases $z, w$ belong to the vertical rays bounding $F$). From this, you conclude that $f$ descends to an injective holomorphic map
$$
h: \mathfrak D\to \mathbb C. 
$$
Verifying that
$$h(\mathfrak D)=f(F)=D^*:=\{w\in \mathbb C: 0<|w|\le 1\}$$
is a good exercise in complex analysis.

The claim $z_p(p)=0$ is a horrible abuse of notation. What they are saying is that by composing the biholomorphic maps
$$
D^*_i\stackrel{\phi_i}{\to} \mathfrak D\stackrel{h}{\to} D^*
$$
one obtains a biholomorphic map $h_i: D^*_i\to D^*$. One can prove that $h_i$ extends to a holomorphic map $g_i: D_i\to D=\{w: |w|\le 1\}$. This is a consequence of Riemann removable singularities theorem. To see that $g_i(p)=0$ is another good exercise in complex analysis: You check that if $A, B$ are open subsets of $\mathbb C$ both containing $0$, $g: A\to B$ is a holomorphic map such that $g(A-\{0\})=B-\{0\}$ and $g: A-\{0\}\to B-\{0\}$ is biholomorphic, then $g(0)=0$.
For Shimizu's lemma, see
Beardon, Alan F., The geometry of discrete groups, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 91. New York - Heidelberg - Berlin: Springer-Verlag. XII, 337 p. (1983). ZBL0528.30001.
or in Lemma 2.21 (read also the proof of Theorem 2.22) in
Imayoshi, Yoichi; Taniguchi, Masahiko, An introduction to Teichmüller spaces, Tokyo: Springer-Verlag. xii, 279 p. (1992). ZBL0754.30001.

Wow! Thank you very much, I will study it in detail. I really appreciate it.
